# Load php response to div on the same page after uploading files

Tags: php, jquery, upload

i am uploading the files to PHP script. it process and give response. i want to load that response in the div or frame on same web page. now the following script giving response in the blank web page. please help me to solve this.
php:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init() {
if(top.uploadDone) top.uploadDone();
}
window.onload=init;
</script>
<body>
<?php
$fn = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] : false);
if ($fn) {
file_put_contents(
    'uploads/' . $fn,
    file_get_contents('php://input')
);
echo "$fn uploaded";
exit();
}
else {
// form submit
$files = $_FILES['fileselect'];
//print $files['name'];
foreach ($files['error'] as $id => $err) {
    if ($err == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $fn = $files['name'][$id];
        move_uploaded_file(
            $files['tmp_name'][$id],
            'uploads/' . $fn
        );
        if($id==1)
        {
            $filename = 'uploads/' . $fn;
            $fp = fopen( $filename, "r" ) or die("Couldn't open $filename");
               $line = fgets($fp);
               fclose($fp);
               $arr = split(",",$line);
               for($i=2;$i< count($arr);$i++)
                {
                    print '<input type="checkbox" name="traits" value="1">'.$arr[$i]."<br>";
                }

        }
    }
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Jquery:**

```
   function init() {
document.getElementById("upload").onsubmit=function() {
    document.getElementById("upload").target = "Analysis";
    document.getElementById("Analysis").onload = uploadDone;    }
 }
 function uploadDone() { //Function will be called when iframe is loaded
var ret = frames['Analysis'].document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;
}
```

**HTML script:**

```
            <div id="content_column">


            <form id="upload" action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <fieldset>
            <div id="Geno" style="display:none">
            <strong>Select Genotypic File</strong>
            <input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />
            <div>
                <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]"  />
            </div> 
            </div>
 <P>
            <div id="Peno" style="display:none">
            <strong>Select Penotypic File</strong>

            <div>
                <input type="file" id="fileselect1" name="fileselect[]"   />
            </div>
            </div>
 <P>
            <div id="Other" style="display:none">
            <strong>Select Other Files*</strong>
            <div>
                <input type="file" id="fileselect2" name="fileselect[]"    multiple="multiple" />
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="submitbutton" style="display:none">
                <INPUT TYPE="Submit" VALUE="Upload" />
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
        <iframe id="Analysis" name="Analysis" src="" ></iframe>
        </div>
```

Thank you in adavance. .

Comment: Do the files actually get uploaded via the ajax that way?  It looks like you are trying but I am pretty sure the only way you can upload files with your code is via actually submitting the page.

Comment: @Jon It is possible to upload files via AJAX, although not exactly in the way the OP is doing.  I have done this in the past (although don't have that code handy right now).

Comment: @AleksG Oh, I know it's possible with ajax, and becoming even increasingly easier with HTML5, I was just curious if the OP was expecting it to work without an addition library or anything that doesn't require rewriting almost all the client side code.